# Selenium 2 + WebDriver + .NET: Can't retrieve text of select's options if select is "display:none;"

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, nunit, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have this select on a page:

```
<select multiple="" class="recipientsList" name="Recipients[]" id="To" style="display: none;">
    <option value="User-6" class="">Coordinator, Test</option>
    <option value="Course-4" class="">New Course 1</option>
    <option value="UserType-6" class="">Coordinators</option>
    <option value="UserTypeInCourse-4-6" class="">New Course 1 Coordinator</option>
</select>
```

And I'm running this test:

```
public IWebDriver WebDriver
{
    get 
    { 
        // gets the current WebDriver instance, set up elsewhere at the beginning
        // of the fixture
        return ScenarioContext.Current.WebDriver(); 
    }
}

public void SelectTest()
{
    // code to navigate to proper page

    var options = WebDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("select.recipientsList option"));

    Assert.That(options, Is.Not.Empty, "No options found.");
    Assert.That(!options.Any(option => string.IsNullOrEmpty(option.Text)), "Some or all options have blank text.");
    // Actual useful assert
}
```

The second assert is failing because all of the elements in the `options` collection has empty string as their Text objects. It works if I remove the JavaScript on the page that adds the `display:none;` style. This is not a permanent solution though, as this select needs to be hidden, as it is extended by [FCBKcomplete](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html).

**How do I get the text of hidden select options with Selenium 2/WebDriver in .NET?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebDriver is designed to emulate the real user interactions. If something is not visible, then the real user cannot see it and WebDriver cannot see it either.

You can emulate the user actions - click, hover or whatever makes your select visible - and then find your select's options and inspect them.

Comment: This makes sense. We'll have to figure out how to find the information from the auto-complete drop-down that FCBKComplete renders, I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: Also you can execute some JavaScript that will change display property and then get the text. You can do it by casting IWebDriver to IJavascriptExecutor (I am using Java so I may have mistakes in interface names) to execute script

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue. I found that if I retrieved all of the elements and looped through them, I could determine which ones were set to display by JS or CSS and then interact with them.

I have a form field that has the same name with a dynamic ID attached, like "fieldname_"+id as the field id. Here's the sample code:

```
List<WebElement> displayNames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'calendarForm_calendarDisplayNameM')]"));

int name_count = 1;
for (WebElement thisDisplayName : displayNames) {
    RenderedWebElement element = (RenderedWebElement)thisDisplayName;
    if (element.isDisplayed()) {
        String calendarDisplayNameText = testCalendarName + "_display_" + name_count; 
        thisDisplayName.sendKeys(calendarDisplayNameText);
        name_count++;
    }
}
```